Generating lotteries on subsets
I am facing the following problem:
A set $X=\{x_1,x_2.....x_m\}$ is equipped with a distribution $\vec{p}=p_1,p_2....p_m$. For a given integer $2 \leq k \leq m-1$, I need to define a lottery $L$ on all the subsets of $X$ of size $k$ that "respects" $\vec{p}$ in the following sense: If $W \subset X,\ |W|=k$ is the subset picked by $L$, we want $Pr(x_i \in W)=k \cdot p_i\ \forall 1 \leq i \leq m$. We may also assume that $p_i \leq \frac{1}{k}\ \forall i$.
Technically, this can be described as finding a positive (in all entries) solution $\vec{L}$ to  $A\vec{L}=k\vec{p}$ where $A$ is an $m$ by $\binom{m}{k}$ binary matrix in which the sum of every row is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ and every column's sum  is $k$.
I'll be happy for anything relevant that you believe could help me here.
Thanks!
